# Nothing on display, after attempting to replace screen

Tags: screen, hardware, touchscreen

My I9505 screen was broken, so I attempted to replace the screen. After doing so, I noticed that the pins (on motherboard) to which the display cable connects too looked to be damaged. 
After everything was connected etc.  I then turned my phone on. And although sound emerged and lights lit up, nothing appeared on the screen. 
(I'm assuming the problem is with the pins described above)
A picture of the motherboard is below.

[image: Motherboard Image]

Is there anything that can be done to repair the motherboard, so images will be displayed on the screen. Without paying for a new motherboard?

P.S I have tested the new replacement screen on another I9505 and it worked perfectly ( so the fault is definitely with my i9505's hardware)